# Функция выполняется раньше другой (AJAX, jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, функции

Есть функция, но почему-то `$.get` выполняется раньше чем `writeMeSubmit`. 
Я это понял, потому что в `writeMeSubmit` лежит запись в файл, а ниже - чтение из файла, и чтение выполняется как бы на шаг назад, т.е при первом клике данные те же, при втором клике опять первые, а при третьем - вторые и т.д. Что вообще может быть не так? почему вторая функция выполняется раньше первой?

```
$('.send').on ( 'click',

function() {

 writeMeSubmit($('.send_form'));

$.get("../action/chat_send.php?message="+$('.text').val(), function(){ 
        $('.text').val('');
        refresh_chat();         
    });

} 

);
```

код функции `writeMeSubmit`:

```
function writeMeSubmit(form){

var formData = new FormData();


jQuery.each($('#file_v')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formData.append('file_v', file);
});


$.ajax({
    url: "../action/ajax_form.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType : "json", 
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,         
    data: formData, 
    success: function(data){
        return;
    }
});

return false;
```

}

Comment: потому что код внутри `writeMeSubmit` выполняет асинхронные действия

Comment: я привел код этой функции, именно его надо подправить, или копаться в php файлах?

Answer (score 0):

```
function writeMeSubmit(form, cb) {
  var formData = new FormData();
  jQuery.each($('#file_v')[0].files, function(i, file) {
    formData.append('file_v', file);
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: "../action/ajax_form.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType : "json", 
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,         
    data: formData, 
    success: function(data){
      cb();
    }
  });
}

$('.send').on( 'click', function() {
  writeMeSubmit($('.send_form'), function() {
    $.get("../action/chat_send.php?message="+$('.text').val(), function(){ 
      $('.text').val('');
      refresh_chat();         
    });
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Вставил этот код, но теперь сообщения перестали отправляться

Comment: Так тоже не помогает